# How to save the selected value of checkboxlist in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to save the values of checkbox in an array using javascript or jquery.
My checkboxlist is inside the datalist. Whenever the user select an item, I want to add the value of that selected item to a array.

```
ASPX :

 <asp:DataList ID="dl_Groups_1" RepeatColumns="1"  runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dl_Groups_1_ItemDataBound" RepeatDirection="vertical" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ID="chk_Group_1" Text='<%# Eval("category_type") %>' Value='<%# Eval("service_type_category_id") %>' onclick="OnGroupClick" />
            <asp:CheckBoxList  CssClass="line" runat="server" ID="chkServiceType_1" DataValueField="ServiceTypeID" DataTextField="Name" EnableViewState="true">
            </asp:CheckBoxList> 
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

I tried the below to, get the items that are slected, but i am struck up here...

```
function test() {
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert(this);
        }
    });
}
```

When i do this, i get alert message as "ON" and not the value. And where do i call the javascript to keep the array updated on selecting and un selecting the items in checkboxlist ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrValues = new Array();
function test() {
    $(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if (this.checked && arrValues.indexOf(this.value) == -1) {
            arrValues.push(this.value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where do i call this function test() ?

Comment: Other person says **Whenever the user select an item** So why iteration? and why not the click event ?

Comment: @Pankaj Garg I just base on his code to show how to add item to array

Comment: @PhongVo where do i call this function, inorder to add the checked items to arrya ?

Comment: @Anuya I just create a sample that will bind `onclick` event to checkbox to add value and remove it out of array [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDud3/)

Answer (score 0):

use `map()`

```
 var selectedValue= $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
     return this.value;
 }).get();

console.log(selectedValue);
```

selectedValue will have all the checked value in array..

Comment: Other person says **Whenever the user select an item** So why iteration? and why not the click event ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var val;
$('#<%= chkServiceType_1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   val = $("#<%= chkServiceType_1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(){
          return this.value;
       }).get();
})
```